# Is there anyway to run cmd commands through javascript?

Tags: javascript, cmd

I'm attempting to create a webpage that submits a form full of information. Some of this information needs to be pulled automatically (e.g. `whoami`). Is there anyway to run the command `whoami` through javascript so I can store it as a variable?

I understand this may not be possible as it would be a MASSIVE security risk, but if that's not possible is there anyway to run a file (like a batch file) on the pc and pull information from that?

Comment: You want to pull the user's system information and/or run commands on their PC from your webpage?  That is a massive security issue.

Comment: @hkpeprah Get back to work Ford :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no pure-javascript solution to this in the browser.  You can't launch arbitrary processes and you can't read files.

There are a few options: depending on what information you need, you might be able to get it from Flash or a Java applet, which can make it available to your javascript.  Your specific case talks about the current user, which you could get just by requiring authentication on your site.  This would make it available to the server, which could write that information to the page.